# Painting a child of type RenderRepaintBoundary fails

Tags: flutter

I try to paint the same child twice in my custom `RenderProxyBox`. This works like a charm with Container, Column, Rows or something similar. But if i try to use a scrollable child like List or `SingleChildScrollView` the content is only drawn one time. Are anyone know why this happens. Is it a bug, or need I use another base class for my CustomRenderObject to achieve this?

[image: Top normal behavior, bottom list wrong behavior]

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter 3D Cube Effect',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        onDrawerChanged: (isOpened) {},
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CustomRenderObjectWidget(
                  child: Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(child: const Icon(Icons.ac_unit, size: 100,)),
                  const SizedBox(child: const Icon(Icons.save, size: 100,)),
                ],
              )),
              Expanded(
                child: CustomRenderObjectWidget(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 40,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: Text("Item: $index"),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomRenderObjectWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const CustomRenderObjectWidget({Key? key, required Widget child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => CustomRenderObject();
}

class CustomRenderObject extends RenderProxyBox {
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (size.isEmpty || child == null) return;
    context.paintChild(child!, offset);
    context.paintChild(child!, offset + Offset(100, 100));
  }

  @override
  Size computeDryLayout(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return _performDryLayout(
        constraints: constraints,
        layoutChild: ChildLayoutHelper.dryLayoutChild);
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    size = _performDryLayout(
        constraints: constraints, layoutChild: ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild);
  }

  Size _performDryLayout(
      {required BoxConstraints constraints,
      required ChildLayouter layoutChild}) {
    if (child == null) {
      return Size.zero;
    }
    return layoutChild(child!, constraints);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88810

Comment: Someone an idea???